# Design tips for large database tables?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

A Database newbie here.

I would like to plan a sales invoice database in which millions of records/rows will be added  a month.
The data inside is not that heavy but a few information like `id,amount, etc...`
The problem is that table needs to be updated very (very) frequently.
I am concerned that table will grow so quickly and slow down the system in the future.
I am looking for a general design tips how should I update that kind of table.
I have some other tables in my schema but that table is the most important one and the most frequently updated.
Is there any design/tip/architecture so I do not have to  update that table directly.

Here is my platform in brief.

```
Application : java/spring mvc
Database    : mysql
OS          : CentOS 6
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.  I have edited your post to make it more readable. You can click on the orange `?` if you need help with the layout of a question.

Comment: If it's just a single table, and the results is needed just from this table (and not requiring complex joins)... I guess if you index appropriate columns, you will be good to go.

Comment: Umm. I need both insert and update on that table. My table will be 12 millions after one year, should I still go for it?

Comment: 12 million is not a large table in database terms.

Comment: thanks, i learned a bunch today.:P

Answer (score 1):

Rule 1: don't worry about performance before slowness hits you.

Rule 2: normalize those tables up to at least 3NF

Rule 3: If you have lots of updates, go easy on the indexes and do not declare unique indexes.

```
do something like:

id integer not null primary key auto_increment  <<-- simple primary key
amount decimal(10,2) not null
.....
```

Rule 4: The size of a table does not affect the insert speed.  *(Unless you have unique indexes)*

Tip: Use InnoDB.

Comment: thanks for the tips, my monster table will only have one primary-key index,(id). but I also need insert and update. any more tips? Thanks

Comment: @darkcloudbird, yes, don't worry, updates are not an issue as long as you don't try and update everything. Invoices do not have many updates anyway. Just use a different table for invoices that are not final yet and a final_invoice table for invoices that are sent out (and thus set in stone)

Comment: one other thing that might help is to consider whether you can housekeep your monster table on a regular basis in order to keep the data volumes down. For example, would it be feasible to add a lastModified column, specify a default value of now() on it for both insert and update and then archive all rows with a lastModified value over x days to another table for reporting/analysis? May not be possible (depends on the nature of the data) but might help.

Comment: Thanks Tom. My initial idea is very similar to what you suggested, but I can not archive data because what we are implementing is like a billing system, our customer may pay the invoice anytime he/she wants (of course with the late fee). any idea?